# Write method group_by on my own

Tags: ruby, group-by

I need to write the method `group_by` by myself. This is what I have so far:

```
module Enumerable
  def group_by(&b)
    solution = {}
    self.each {|key,val|
      b.call(var)
      solution = { key=> (val) }
    }
   end
end

ary = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

p ary.group_by() { |i| i%3 }
```

I don't get it. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Hi - you seem new here.
It really helps us to help you if you include the error message that you get when you try to run your code. Right now it's really difficult for us to tell what you are actually asking us*. "I don't get it" doesn't narrow that down at all. So you are asking us to guess what you need instead of just telling us. In future - can you please give us some more detail on your question? It will really hep us to help you better (which means your question gets answered quicker).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure how I can help apart from post a solution, but maybe some description with what you find difficult might help?

Few issues I notice:

- You are using passing two arguments into the block when the array only has 1, the value
- You call the block with `var` which doesn't exist in the current scope, maybe you meant val?
- You dont check to see if anything already exists in the new solution dictionary
- You overwrite the solution dictionary every time you loop over a new value in the array

Here is what I came up with:

```
module Enumerable

  def group_by
    solution = {}
    each do |value|
      key = yield value
      if solution.key?(key)
        solution[key] << value
      else
        solution[key] = [value]
      end
    end
    solution
  end

end

ary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p ary.group_by { |i| i % 3 }
```

output:

```
{1=>[1, 4], 2=>[2, 5], 0=>[3]}
```

you might want to check if a block has been given incase someone tries to use the function wrong, consider using the statement `unless block_given?` but maybe you can try implement this yourself.

Comment: Taht's perfect, exactly what i need. Just for the understanding. "key = yield value" iterates every value and puts them into the variable "key"? and what exactly is solution.key?(key) doing?

Comment: @user2409416 `key?(key) → Returns true if the given key is present in hash.` and `key = yield value` calls the block with the value to get the key (what to group the dictionary by) so you can see add the value to the dictionary with that key.

Comment: Good solution. You should return an `Enumerator` if there's no block given though.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune you are right, I didn't know if it would be too confusing for the OP. but `return to_enum(:group_by) unless block_given?` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
module Enumerable
  def group_by &b; inject({}){|h, e| (h[b.call(e)] ||= []).push(e); h} end
end

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].group_by{|i| i % 3}
# => {1 => [1, 4, 7, 10], 2 => [2, 5, 8], 0 => [3, 6, 9]}
```

Comment: A 'clever' solution, smaller than mine but not too sure if its that easy to understand for a novice user. A vote for niceness though!

Comment: Looks pretty good, but i think my prof. woun't believe me that i wrote that :/

Comment: Nope i wount! I asked because i want to understand what i'm doing and the first solution will help me more but of course your solution is well done...that's all i wanted to say -.-"

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for comparison:

```
module Enumerable
  def group_by
    {}.tap do |group|
      each{ |value| (group[ yield(value) ] ||= []) << value }
    end
  end
end
```

- uses `tap` to avoid the unsightly pattern of

  ```
  thing = {}
  # do stuff with thing
  thing # return it
  ```
- uses `||=` to create the new collection array of not already present

Alternatively:

```
module Enumerable
  def group_by
    Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=[] }.tap do |group|
      each{ |value| group[ yield(value) ] << value }
      group.default = nil # remove the default_proc when done
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You seem to like `tap`. I had learned a few usages of it from you long time ago.

Comment: @sawa I do indeed! I know that some frown on using it for this pattern, preferring `each_with_object`, but that is both more typing and (a tiny bit) slower.

Comment: I like your style better. It is conceptually more natural as the original receiver is what comes out (modified) as the output.

Comment: I like the second one pretty much. The answer from Oliver Atkinson is probably the best for beginners(and easy to replicable) but this one is great. THANKS to all of you! ...Will come again for the next question

Comment: @user2409416 Please make sure to Accept Oliver's answer, then, by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @Phrogz: Indeed it is interesting to see `#tap` used in this basic way. And the code with `tap` actually doesn't look that bad... Although my love for `tap` is above average, looking at this, it seems to me that I'm still underusing it.

Answer (score 2):

From my [backports gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/1.8.7/enumerable/group_by.rb):

```
module Enumerable
  def group_by
    return to_enum(:group_by) unless block_given?
    result = {}
    each do |o|
      key = yield(o)
      ary = result.fetch(key){ result[key] = [] }
      ary << o
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Contrary to all solutions presented so far, it passes [RubySpec](http://rubyspec.org/).

Comment: When I see Marc-Andre's face, I just upvote without reading :-)

Comment: May I just ask of you to say something about your denser code style? As in `fetch(yield(o)){|key| ... []}`. Don't you have problems reading it after yourself? (I would written it with more spaces...) Is that a matter of personal preference, or just me not being seasoned enough? Also, may I ask, is it difficult to check whether something passes RubySpec?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky It's true that this line was quite compact and not super readable. I've edited my answer, I think it's now more readable.

Comment: just out of interest, why doesn't my answer pass RubySpec?